# Add empty constructors via jaxb from a XML Schema

Tags: xml, constructor, jaxb, schema, xjc

Is it possible to add the empty constructor via jaxb from a XML-Schema?

I could already add the implementation of Serializable, but missing the constructor in its files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <xs:annotation>
        <!-- adds implements Serializable-->
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jxb:globalBindings>
                <jxb:serializable uid="1" />
            </jxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
[...]
```

Maven is set as follows:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- where to put generated classes -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>

                            <!-- package name? -->
                            <packageName>com.COMPANNAME.xsd.classes</packageName>

                            <!-- which sources -->
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/resources/com/COMPNAME/xsd/name.xsd</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Why do you need an empty constructor?

Comment: I want to use those classes as serializated-classes for server/client communication. And as for gwt you need an empty constructor - as far as I unterstood. Anyhow, I cannot use them anyway 'cause of the annotation in those classes are not serializable :-/

Comment: If there is no constructor (default in JAXB/XJC-generated classes) then there's a default constructor (which is essentially an empty constructor). No need to generate `public MyClass(){}`.